# How to avoid: TypeError: Descriptors cannot not be created directly. But leave the last protobuf version in project

Tags: python, protocol-buffers, grpc, mysql-connector-python

I have `grpc` server that uses `protobuf` and needs version  3.20.x or lower.

Also in the project I connect to `mysql 8` and it requires a later version.

How can I connect this in one project?

Set `PROTOCOL_BUFFERS_PYTHON_IMPLEMENTATION=python` is the only variant? Or is it possible to somehow use different versions of `protobuf` in one code? (to `grpc 3.20, to mysql 4.20`)

I know only about Set `PROTOCOL_BUFFERS_PYTHON_IMPLEMENTATION`

Comment: Due to a bug in the Python Protobuf C extension, Connector/Python only supports protobuf>=4.21.1,<=4.21.12. Also, 3.20.x protobuf generated stubs are not compatible with 4.x. If you require protobuf 3.20.x, you can install Connector/Python 8.0.33. But, if you're not using the X DevAPI implementation of Connector/Python, you can use the latest version 8.1.0 and force the installation of protobuf 3.20.x, since it's not used by the classic protocol.